# Does `persistentEntityRegistry.eventStream` really took atleast ~8-12 seconds to get triggered

Tags: apache-kafka, lagom

Just wanted what is the possible reasons why my `persistentEntityRegistry.eventStream` takes an approximately ~8-12 seconds to be emitted.

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured out that its the cassandra that's taking a delay. What I've done is to set `cassandra-query-journal.eventual-consistency-delay` to `200ms`.

My references are the following:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lagom-framework/cLXf6r5Ouw4
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/TH8hL-A8I4k/discussion